# Limiting SMB/CIFS speed in windows 10

Tags: iscsi, server-message-block

I googled but cant find anything about this.
We have a diskless environment where our 28 client boots from ISCSI based diskless program called ccboot.

Now, the clients also need to access file share from a different win 2012 server using SMB protocol.

Problem is, the SMB traffic is quite big, usually the data transferred is in 2-4 GB size. 
And this causes some clients to reboot, maybe because 1GB environment is not enough to support this kind of scenario?

I'm not 100% sure that SMB traffic is causing the reboots,
But i want to try limiting SMB / CIFS traffic from client side,
is it possible? Client is running 1703 windows 10.

I have limited the SMB traffic from SMB server side using this method
http://fixmyitsystem.com/2013/12/QOS01.html, but it doesn't seem to help, random reboot still happens.

Edit : i'm using these 
Iscsi server 10g > CRS226-24G-2S+RM > Tp link sg2452
The clients are connected to both switches, smb server is connected to tp link

I tried editing DSCP priority and schedule mode..
Schedule is saved, but DSCP priority always returns to blank value, even after pressing apply and save config.. any idea why? Sorry im completely new at managed switch.. [managed switch DSCP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc7MH.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Running iSCSI and normal, high-volume traffic on the same infrastructure can be a problem.

The SMB traffic may be suppressing the iSCSI access to the system disk which at least for Windows is a major problem.

The best apporach is to physically separate the traffic (VLANs & interconnects). If you can't and can't at least widen interconnect bottlenecks (core to access switches) you might want to prioritize traffic, so that iSCSI is preferred and doesn't get dropped. If you post details to your network, layout and hardware configurations we might be able to figure out how to do the prioritization.

**edit** after your comment:

The TL-SG2452 is a poor choice for iSCSI - it's only got 1.5 MB buffer. With a single GbE link, this buffer is exhausted in just .01 s...

Given you're running everything on a single link without VLANs on the client side(?), and storage & client are likely not using DSCP, you need to prioritize by source port, i.e. your iSCSI storage uplink.  You'll probably want DSCP 0x0a (high priority, low drop probability). I'd set schedule mode to *WRR-Mode* and use TC2 for iSCSI, giving a 4:1 priority.

Comment: I presume the prioritization is done on client side? And how would i do this on windows 10 client using realtek nic?

Comment: No. The prioritization needs to be done in the network, on the switches. When upstream traffic is also a problem, then you'd need to configure it on each client as well.

Comment: As long as you do VLANs and QoS for a proper traffic separation you'll be fine!

Comment: Hmm i'm gonna look into this again, my tp link switch sg2452 is supposed to be capable for this, but i had some troubles configuring it in the past

Comment: I forgot to mention i also got crs mikrotik 10g switch coming from iscsi server. I have updated my question with complete specs.. Any better switch recommendation? Managed switch is kinda rare in my country

Comment: I tried changing DSCP Value but it keeps reverting back to blank.. any idea why?

Comment: I decided to get another switch.. would dell x1052 be a good option? Its only got 8Mb packet buffer.. when you said 1.5MB, did you mean 1.5 megabits or megabytes? Because i cant find this data about tlsg2452 anywhere..

Comment: @denywinarto See http://static.tp-link.com/resources/document/TL-SG2452_V1_Datasheet.pdf - "Package Buffer Memory 1.5 MB" - that should be megabyte. 8 Mb should be megabit, that's a single megabyte; can't really imagine that for a switch with 10G uplinks. Decent datasheets are usually scarce from Dell though...

Comment: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/network-switches/f/866/t/19662936 their staff said so though.. if it's true then it's worse than TL SG2452, 1.5 MB > 1MB.. hmm that seems to be the only 48p 1G + 1SFP+ with reasonable price.. other options are quite expensive

Comment: @denywinarto Even more confusion - "port buffer" could mean it's a dedicated per-port buffer. Possibly, it could also be a per-queue buffer. 1 MB total packet buffer on an otherwise decent switch is hardly imaginable. Well, crap documentation...

Comment: Linksys lgs552 seems to be another option, 2x 8 mbits buffer https://www.linksys.com/ca/support-article?articleNum=141400 any thoughts?

Comment: Another tempting one, Ubiquity ES-48 500W, 24Mbits packet buffer according to this  https://community.ubnt.com/t5/EdgeSwitch/EdgeSwitch-Performance/td-p/1211442 cheapest too, but Its got 3 1 star reviews (Dead after 1 year) and only 1 year warranty though.. hmm tough choice

Comment: The choice is yours. Product recommendations are off-topic here as on most SE sites.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a powerShell command [Set-SmbBandwidthLimit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/set-smbbandwidthlimit?view=win10-ps) to limit the SMB bandwidth

Comment: This is what i did on my smb server, i lowered the value until the most acceptable value for client, but reboot still occurs.. lowering it further would not be ideal for the clients.. running it on clients might also help but i googled and it doesnt seem to be compatible with win 10